# Is there anyway to turn on a simple light or motor with no microcontroller via your computer?

Tags: control, control-system

Is their a way i can directly turn on things without the use of a micro controller, i feel that for the applications that I am working on I can run whatever I want from the computer alone without going through programing a micro controller.

Comment: there are wireless solutions, X10 solutions, and no doubt many others that either hook up directly via usb or you can talk to via bluetooth or wireless network/wifi (or you talk wired ethernet and the device is using an access point to connect to the network).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A USB FTDI cable and libftdi.

- http://hackaday.com/2009/09/22/introduction-to-ftdi-bitbang-mode/
- https://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/

Comment: I like using micro controllers but I feel better if i can get the software i am writing to work with the outside world, turn on light, etc without having multiple programing platforms on my computer and complicated hardware.

Comment: It's just a USB cable. Breakout boards are not mandatory, I suppose they are just multiplexers. If you want it portable, use a Raspberry Pi 1 B+ (can run fine on 2.5 watts)

Comment: user400344 sorry, I was meaning to thank you, i just forgot to add that to the comment.

Comment: You're welcome. Plenty of code snippets to be found on google 

Answer (score 1):

You can use USB-RS232 cables to do simple I/O. You don't even need any drivers for the OS. 
Simply use the modem signals as inputs and outputs:

[image]

Virtually all input signals with accept simple TTL levels but the outputs will swing +/-7 V typically, though you can clamp them.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is old enough you can use the [parallel port](http://www.instructables.com/id/Home-Automation-Control-a-Relay-with-your-Paralle/) (or add one with a pci card) to give you 'GPIO-like' functionality on a PC.

You can then use a transistor relay combination to switch power from a PC port.
Here is an example of a circuit to give you [5V from a parallel port](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/97370/how-to-regulate-parallel-port-pin-output-voltage-to-5v)

Comment: that works as well I still have a windows xp computer working with ribbon cables and floppy drives. my windows 98 computer just bite the dust a year ago.

Comment: Don't forget that the venerable serial port has a few general-purpose dio lines that you can easily program as well.  Then wire to a relay driver chip or ssr...